# dynamically create / append to zip from multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, zip

I have a situation where thousands o files are created for a user by multiple backend instances, and then they're uploaded to AWS S3 / Azure Storage. After all the files are created, the user wants to download them as a zip. I can create the zip and then get a pre-signed URL, but I tried few archiving solutions and all of them are just taking too much time (hours).

Is there any way of creating the zip dynamically from the multiple backend instances? I want append to zip after each file creation, from any backend instance.

Comment: How many files are being zipped? How big are the files? Amazon S3 is an immutable storage service, so you cannot Append or Edit files. Therefore, it will be quite a challenge to collect files from multiple compute instances and zip-up the results.

Comment: 10K+ files * 0.1-10 MB

Answer (score 1):

Zip itself supports the use case you want. For example, [zip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) command in Linux:

> When given the name of an existing zip archive, **zip will** replace identically named entries in the zip archive (matching the relative names as stored in the archive) or **add entries for new names**.

You need to persist the working zip file somewhere in a file system though. The most obvious choice I can think of is EFS, so that multiple instances can mount the file system and access the zip file.

If you don't want to modify the existing instances/workloads, you can even mount EFS on Lambda. Then set S3 trigger for the Lambda to update zip file every time a new file is uploaded.

I think you can not use only S3 for this, because you cannot update S3 objects. Then you need to download/upload for every new file, which is really not ideal.

Comment: I checked the AWS EFS documents and it seems like a good solution. I'll try soon. How about downloading the zip? I don't think it supports the above URLs.

Comment: I don't think zip actually supports this use case. It does support modifications of existing zip files, but not multiple concurrent modifications of a single zip file. So multiple instances trying to write to append to a single zip file at the same time are either going to create a corrupted file, or one server's changes would be overwritten by another server's changes. The concurrency aspect of the question is the problem.

Comment: @johnykes Yeah EFS alone does not provide API to directly download. Once done/as and when needed, you can place the zip in S3, and generate pre-sign URL the same way.

Comment: @MarkB Yeah I'm just talking about the zip format supporting append despite being a compressed format. The process needs to acquire write lock when updating the zip, and has to have some handling to wait and retry if the file is being locked. This waiting takes some time, but hopefully it can be distributed throughout the day, so that it is still better than the current situation that takes hours.