# download thousands of media files from AWS S3 / Azure Storage using browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, browser, download, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to find a solution to allow users to download thousands of media files (10K +, 0.1-10MB each) from AWS S3 / Azure Storage.

First, I tried to archive the files and use a pre-signed URL to download the zip. It works, but its just
takes too much time (hours) - [dynamically create / append to zip from multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71523931/dynamically-create-append-to-zip-from-multiple-instances/71524443?noredirect=1#comment126422200_71524443)

Is there another solution, like just downloading / streaming them via browser, without archiving them? Archiving doesn't help too much anyway (15-30%).

Comment: Wouldn't "download *thousands* of media files" by the very nature of downloading "takes too much time (hours)"?

Comment: at least we don't waste time archiving the files. for example, for 1000 media files, the fastest archiving solution I found took ~10 minutes, and the downloading process just 1 minute. so in this case, downloading the files without archiving them could take less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Well tbh this isn't my area so I'll upvote your question in better hopes to attract someone who knows.

Comment: I realize this is tagged javascript, but if you're willing to run a process on a machine somewhere, you can create a zip file from S3 data in a reasonable amount of time by downloading the content, archiving it, then sending it back to s3, for example [this script](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/2a385620bf2cfcc5112b0b397aebaee5) works in about six minutes, not hours.

Comment: Why do you want users to download "thousands of files"? How will they be using those files? Can't you simply provide one Zip file? Are these technical users who might be able to use the AWS CLI?